# Create and print to a new file if file is specified, else just std.out

Tags: python, printing

I'm creating a bingo card. Part of the assignment is to print the card to the screen, unless the user specifies a file, in which case it will print the card to that file. I will be creating the file that they specify.

I've gotten it to print to the screen perfectly, but I can't figure out how to create the file and print the bingo card to it. I know that I can use `open(file) as f` and `f.write`, but when I do that it kept coming up with errors and I couldn't print to stdout anymore.

Any suggestions on how to do this? This is the code, my teacher specified the function names, I just have to fill in the code on how to do it. I call it with `test.print()`.

```
def print(self, file=sys.stdout):
    """void function:
    Prints a card to the screen or to an open file object"""
    # if file == sys.stdout:
    #     f = sys.stdout
    # else:
    #     f = open(str(file), 'w+')
    tableCorner = "+"
    tableMiddle = "-----"
    tableSide = "|"
    total = 0
    row = 0
    print("\nCard #" + str(self.getId()))
    while row < self.size:
        # prints horizontal divider
        while total < self.size:
            print(tableCorner + tableMiddle, end="")
            total += 1
        print(tableCorner)
        total = 0
        # prints line with numbers
        while total < self.size:
            print(tableSide + str(self.card.getNext()).center(5, " "), end="")
            total += 1
        print(tableSide)
        total = 0
        row += 1
    while total < self.size:
        print(tableCorner + tableMiddle, end="")
        total += 1
    print(tableCorner)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting `sys.stdout` as the default parameter, try:

```
def print(self, file=None):
    if not file is None:
        sys.stdout = open(file)
```

and leaving the rest of the code the same. Setting sys.stdout to a file object will cause prints to end up there instead of the normal stdout. Keep in mind that using open outside of a with block is not typically recommended, so you might want to restructure things accordingly.

EDIT: Two things:
1. I made a quick demo to show what happens when you set sys.stdout to a file object:

```
In [1]: import sys                                                              

In [2]: print('some BODY once told me')                                         
some BODY once told me

In [3]: sys.stdout = open('test.txt','w')                                       
In [4]: print('some BODY once told me')                                         
In [5]: sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__                                             

In [6]: with open('test.txt','r') as f: 
   ...:     print(f.read()) 
   ...:                                                                         

some BODY once told me
```

As you can see, with no change to the `sys.stdout`, the print returns in the ipython console. After changing it to a file called text.txt, it ends up there, and is verified by putting `sys.stdout` back to the original, which is given by `sys.__stdout__`, and printing out the contents of the file.

2. You might not need to worry about using a with block. Trying to close sys.stdout after setting it equal to the file object gave me an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/finchj/programs/anaconda3/envs/finchj/bin/ipython", line 11, in 
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/home/finchj/programs/anaconda3/envs/finchj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/**init**.py", line 125, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/finchj/programs/anaconda3/envs/finchj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 658, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/home/finchj/programs/anaconda3/envs/finchj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 356, in start
    self.shell.mainloop()
  File "/home/finchj/programs/anaconda3/envs/finchj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 498, in mainloop
    self.interact()
  File "/home/finchj/programs/anaconda3/envs/finchj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 478, in interact
    print(self.separate_in, end='')
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Leading me to suspect that cleanup is handled behind the scenes, though I cannot confirm this is the case at this time.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly!!! So Simple I was so close to getting it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!